# Why isnt location.href() working?

Tags: javascript, location-href

I just want the new page to appear in an `iframe` on the current page instead of loading a whole new page.

Here's my code:

```
function salabim(id){
    var gotoo;

    var objid = document.getElementById("pgMaster");

    new Effect.Shake(id);
    return false;

    gotoo=id+".html";
    objid.src=gotoo;
    location.href(gotoo);
}
```

This doesn't work in any browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the code below 'return false;' will not get executed.

Comment: instructor asked to add the code at the end of the function. so he did...

Comment: is `pgMaster` the ID of the iframe?

Comment: As nelson mentioned, everything after return false; is never executed. Put return false; just after your location.href(gotoo); and before the }//end salabim.

Answer (score 4):

Move `return false;` to the end, and use `location.href` like so:

```
location.href = gotoo;
```

Answer (score 2):

`location.href` is an attribute rather than a function, use `location.href = url` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
location.href = gotoo;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `false` before you do anything with `location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return false;` in the middle of your function, so code after that return statement isn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
window.location.href = "YourURL";
```